# How does the AirPodCase identify the nearest device?

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

When opening the Case, your nearest device opens an info screen with the battery charge of case and AirPods. 
However, when I have the iPhone and the iPad lying next to each other. still only the nearest one shows the pop up.

How do the AirPods measure which one is the closest and only pop-up the window on the nearest one?